# jOOQ plain SQL with bind

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I want to use the plain sql for fetching a query, say:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = ... AND lName = ...
```

Now I know I can do

```
this.dsl.fetch(query, "myFirstName", "myLastName");
```

But I want to use binds so I can do

```
final String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fName = :fname AND lName = :lname";
this.dsl
   .fetch(query)
   .bind("fname", "MyFirstName")
   .bind("lname", "MyLastName");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For sure it would be possible, but you must find the right syntax. But do not forget there exists plain JDBC, where this query is *trivial*.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use this hypothetical `fetch(...).bind(...).bind(...)` syntax rather than the `fetch(..., bindValues)` syntax? They seem equivalent